# Oracle 18c - Complex sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle18c

I have a table with following columns:

```
Emp_ID Number
Emp_flag Varchar2(1)
Date_1 Date
Date_2 Date
create_date Date
```

No PK on this table , there are many records with duplicates of Emp_id..

What I need to know, is when a new `Date_1` is entered (so Null to a date, or from Date 1 to Date 2)  on what date that happened.

I can’t just look at a single record to compare `Date_1` with create_date because there are many times in the many records for a given `Emp_ID` when the `Date_1` is simply “copied” to the new record. A `Date_1` may have been originally entered on 02/15/2019 with a value of 02/01/2019.   Now let’s say `Date_2` gets added on 02/12/2020. So the table looks like this:

```
Emp_ID  Emp_flag    Date_1     Date_2      Create_Date
123     Y           Null       Null        1/18/2018
123     Y           02/1/2019  Null        02/15/2019
123     Y           02/1/2019  02/12/2021  02/12/2020
```

I need a SQL query that would tell me that `Emp_ID` 123 had a `Date_1` of 02/1/2019 entered on 02/15/2019 and NOT pick up any other record.

Expected output:

```
Emp_ID  Emp_flag    Date_1     Date_2      Create_Date
123     Y           02/1/2019  Null        02/15/2019
```

Example 2 (notice `date_1` is different):

```
Emp_ID  Emp_flag    Date_1     Date_2      Create_Date
456     Y           Null       Null        1/18/2018
456     Y           10/1/2019  Null        02/15/2019
456     Y           11/2/2019  02/12/2021  02/12/2020
```

Expected output:

```
Emp_ID  Emp_flag    Date_1     Date_2      Create_Date
456     Y           10/1/2019  Null        02/15/2019
456     Y           11/2/2019  02/12/2021  02/12/2020
```

Example 3:

```
Emp_ID  Emp_flag    Date_1     Date_2      Create_Date
456     Y           Null       Null        1/18/2018
456     Y           10/1/2019  Null        02/15/2019
456     Y           10/1/2019  Null        02/15/2019
456     Y           11/2/2019  02/12/2021  02/12/2020
```

Expected output:

```
Emp_ID  Emp_flag    Date_1     Date_2      Create_Date
456     Y           10/1/2019  Null        02/15/2019
456     Y           11/2/2019  02/12/2021  02/12/2020
```

Example 4:

```
Emp_ID  Emp_flag    Date_1     Date_2      Create_Date
456     Y           10/1/2019  Null        02/15/2019
456     Y           10/1/2019  Null        02/16/2019
```

Expected output: No records.

Comment: Do rows ever get updated, or is a new row created for every data change?

Comment: no updates. A new one is created for every data change.

Comment: not fully sure i understand the question. can you give a more elaborate explanation of the criteria required and the expected output

Comment: Please see added examples/expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test for all cases:

```
with t(emp_id, emp_flag, date_1, date_2, create_date) as (
    select 101, 'Y', null,              null,              date '2018-01-18' from dual union all
    select 101, 'Y', date '2019-02-01', null,              date '2019-02-15' from dual union all
    select 101, 'Y', date '2019-02-01', date '2021-02-12', date '2019-02-16' from dual union all
    select 102, 'Y', null,              null,              date '2018-01-18' from dual union all
    select 102, 'Y', date '2019-02-10', null,              date '2019-02-15' from dual union all
    select 102, 'Y', date '2019-02-11', date '2021-02-12', date '2019-02-16' from dual union all
    select 103, 'Y', null,              null,              date '2018-01-18' from dual union all
    select 103, 'Y', date '2019-02-10', null,              date '2019-02-15' from dual union all
    select 103, 'Y', date '2019-02-10', null,              date '2019-02-15' from dual union all
    select 103, 'Y', date '2019-02-11', date '2021-02-21', date '2020-12-02' from dual )
select emp_id, emp_flag, date_1, date_2, create_date
  from (
    select emp_ID, emp_flag, date_1, date_2, create_date,
           lag(date_1) over (partition by emp_id order by create_date) prev_dt1
      from t )
  where date_1 <> nvl(prev_dt1, date_1 - 1);
```

Result:

```
    EMP_ID EMP_FLAG DATE_1      DATE_2      CREATE_DATE
---------- -------- ----------- ----------- -----------
       101 Y        2019-02-01              2019-02-15
       102 Y        2019-02-10              2019-02-15
       102 Y        2019-02-11  2021-02-12  2019-02-16
       103 Y        2019-02-10              2019-02-15
       103 Y        2019-02-11  2021-02-21  2020-12-02
```

---

Edit:

> when there are more than one records with no change in Date_1. It
>   should not return a record for that Emp_id

In this case date_1 is set in first row (id 104). If you want hide rows in such case use:

```
with t(emp_id, emp_flag, date_1, date_2, create_date) as (
    select 104, 'Y', date '2019-02-10', null,              date '2019-02-15' from dual union all
    select 104, 'Y', date '2019-02-10', null,              date '2019-02-16' from dual union all
    select 105, 'Y', date '2019-02-10', null,              date '2019-02-15' from dual union all
    select 105, 'Y', null,              null,              date '2019-02-16' from dual )
select emp_id, emp_flag, date_1, date_2, create_date
  from (
    select emp_ID, emp_flag, date_1, date_2, create_date,
           lag(date_1) over (partition by emp_id order by create_date) prev_dt1, 
           row_number() over (partition by emp_id order by create_date) rn
      from t )
  where (date_1 is not null and prev_dt1 is null and rn > 1)
     or date_1 <> prev_dt1
     or date_1 is null and prev_dt1 is not null;
```

I also added case when previous date was set and now it is null (id 105). If it is not possible or you don't want it then remove last row.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when there are more than one records with no change in Date_1. It should not return a record for that Emp_id, but it does.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Lag` function to check whether the previous value of `date_1` existed or not.

```
SELECT x.emp_id,
       x.date_1,
       x.create_date AS first_date_with_date_1
FROM (
    SELECT t.emp_id,
           t.create_date,
           t.date_1,
           LAG(t.date_1) OVER (PARTITION BY t.emp_id ORDER BY t.create_date) AS last_date_1
    FROM your_table t
) x
WHERE x.date_1 IS NOT NULL
  AND x.last_date_1 IS NULL
```

Comment: If you're looking for changes to `date_1`, not just inserts, then that last `WHERE` condition would just be `AND x.last_date_1 <>  x.date_1`.

Comment: I don't think this works, please see my updates - added expected results and a new example as well.

Comment: @user3224907 If you're looking for any change, rather than just an addition, just do what EricBrandt suggested in the comment above

Comment: This does not work when there are multiple records with the same Date_1. Could you please update to account? Also, if all records have the same Date_1, do not output this Emp_id.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the lag function instead of lead here:

```
with tableA as
(
select 456 as Emp_ID,'Y' as Emp_flag,CAST(NUll as date) as Date_1,CAST(NULL as date) as Date_2,CAST('18Jan2018' as date) as Create_date from dual union
select 456,'Y',CAST('01Oct2019' as date),Null,CAST('15Feb2019' as date) from dual union
select 456,'Y',CAST('02Nov2019' as date),CAST('12Feb2021' as date),CAST('12Feb2020' as date) from dual) 

select x.Emp_ID,x.Emp_flag,x.Date_1,x.Date_2,x.Create_date
from
(select a.*
       ,lag(a.date_1) Over (partition by a.Emp_ID order by a.create_date) as lag_date
from tableA a) x
where x.date_1 is not null and x.date_1<>COALESCE(x.lag_date,CAST('01Jan2100' as date))
```

This will give out the values only when there is a change in date_1. Since NULL comparisons won't work, I have replace them with 1/1/2100. Hope this helps.

Edit:

I checked for a sample like you mentioned and it does seem to be working. If it's not working, kindly share the expected and the result you are getting:

```
with tableA as
(
select 456 as Emp_ID,'Y' as Emp_flag,CAST(NUll as date) as Date_1,CAST(NULL as date) as Date_2,CAST('18Jan2018' as date) as Create_date from dual union
select 456,'Y',CAST('01Oct2019' as date),Null,CAST('15Feb2019' as date) from dual union
select 456,'Y',CAST('01Oct2019' as date),CAST('12Feb2021' as date),CAST('12Feb2020' as date) from dual) 

select x.Emp_ID,x.Emp_flag,x.Date_1,x.Date_2,x.Create_date
from
(select a.*
       ,lag(a.date_1) Over (partition by a.Emp_ID order by a.create_date) as lag_date
from tableA a) x
where x.date_1 is not null and x.date_1<>COALESCE(x.lag_date,CAST('01Jan2100' as date))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when there are more than one records with no change in Date_1. It should not return a record for that Emp_id, but it does.

Comment: Added an edit for a sample like you mentioned...It seems to be working fine